# The email() function in php is giving me a 0 as the email body

Tags: php

I have a simple account creation page that takes the user input and emails it to my email account, but when I check the email it shows a zero as the body.

```
    <form action="" method="post">
    <p style="font-family:latine;">Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></p>
    <br><br>
    <p style="font-family:latine;">Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></p>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Create account">
</form>

<?php
   $user = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];
   $info = $user + $password;
   mail("myemail@gmail.com", "User request", $info);
?>
```

Comment: `$info = $user + $password;` that's JS/C concatenation syntax. Wrap it in quotes `$info = "$user $password";` or  `$info = $user . " " . $password;`

Comment: @Fred-ii- hah, couldn't have been more to the point than that :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky *Thank you vurry mooch*, as ELVIS would say ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing somebody else decided to post an answer:

I'll *explain*:

`$info = $user + $password;` that `+` sign is JS/C concatenation syntax.

Either wrap it in quotes and removing the `+` sign:

```
$info = "$user $password";
```

or use PHP's `.` (dot-period) concatenation syntax:

```
$info = $user . " " . $password;
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

You may also want to wrap your executable code inside a conditional statement and naming the submit button and checking if all fields are not left empty.

Seeing you're using your entire code in one file.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p style="font-family:latine;">Username: 
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></p>
    <br><br>
    <p style="font-family:latine;">Password: 
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></p>

<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create account">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) 
&& !empty($_POST["username"]) 
&& !empty($_POST["password"])){
   $user = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];
   $info = "$user $password";
   mail("myemail@gmail.com", "User request", $info);
   }
?>
```

- Otherwise, you will get notices of undefined indexes on initial page load, when using error reporting.

---

Another thing. You will want to use an additional parameter "From:" in your mail header. Your message may end up in Spam or ignored altogether because of the missing "From:".

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Example pulled from that page:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

> The additional_parameters parameter can be used to pass an additional parameter to the program configured to use when sending mail using the sendmail_path.

```
<?php
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
```

Comment: I ended up putting both variables: `$username` and `$password` in the `mail()` function: `mail("myemail@gmail.com", "User request", $username, $password)` But thanks for the help.

Comment: @yak613 Ok great, glad to hear it. If you feel that my answer did help solve the problem, consider marking it as solved. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
$info = $user + $password;
```

by `$info = $user . $password;`

See String concate: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Can you do that for more than two, like: `$info = $user . $password . $other`?

Comment: check the documentation. you can do it to any number of variables